# Creating line with start and end points which are in another layer using QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, line

In my map, there are lots of points in layer **A**. I want to make a line layer **B** and I want to make start & end points of lines snapping to points in layer A manually.

Can I use points of layer A as a coordinate attribute selection index for my line layer B?

Answer (score 5):

In `Settings->Snapping options`, you can select layers to which the points of a line can snap to.

You may set the snapping radius to 10 pixel in `Settings->Options->Digitizing` , to see the mouse snap to the points of the other layer.

After creation of the line, you may move the nodes with the node tool, where snapping is also working.